# General Probability question

Tags: probability

We toss a coin 300 times. We got 157 heads and 143 tails.

What is the probability of getting a head if we again toss that coin ?

Comment: Fair coin: $\frac{1}{2}$ (assuming that our perception of time and space is accurate).

Answer (score 3):

You might find [Laplace's rule of succession](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession) interesting. This is a result linked to the [Bayesian interpretation of probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability), in which probability is interpreted as a measure of "strenght of belief" rather than of "long-run frequency".

Specifically, suppose that a toin coss may lead to a head with an unknown probability $p=P(Head)$ and that $n$ independent tosses are performed. Say that before observing any toss you believe all values of $p$ to be equally likely (i.e. you don't know if the coin is fair or biased in some way). Also say that you observe $s$ heads during the $n$ tosses. Then Laplace's rule of succession says that you should assign a probability of 
$$\frac{s+1}{n+2}$$
to the statement "the next independent toss will end up heads". In your example, this probability is roughly 52%.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have a fair coin, the probability of getting a head on the next toss is

$$0.5{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

The outcome of each and every toss of the coin is *independent* of prior outcomes. So, even if we tossed a coin 300 times and got 300 heads, the probability of getting a head if we again toss that coin remains $0.5$

Answer (score 1):

If you don't simply assume the coin is fair (there is no reason to make such an assumption), then the best estimate you have is $157/300 \approx 0.523$.

However, the standard deviation on tossing a fair coin $N$ times is $\sigma = 1/2\sqrt{N}$, which in this case would be $\sigma = 0.029$, so the deviation from fair is less than one standard deviation.  Thus there is no reason to assume the coin is not fair, either.

In summary: $$P(head) = 0.523\ \ ^+_-\  0.029 $$

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are assuming the coin is fair. In that case, the tosses are independent of past tosses. In other words, regardless of what information you gave me in previous tosses, my answer would be he same: the probability of obtaining a head given 157 heads and 143 tails is just the probability of getting a head which is $1/2$.

Mathematically:

$P$(Head $\vert 157$ heads and 143 tails = $P$(Head) = 1/2.

I don't know your background, but if the above equation's notation is confusing to you, just disregard it. I think in the case of these types of probability questions, the intuition is more important.